# Eclipse+Pydev sluggish "Variables" window

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I use eclipse+pydev for my python dev and I like it because it easily integrates with Git, etc.
However, recently, I've started experiencing this really weird problem when I debug my python code which I didn't have before:

The "Variables" window, which is supposed to show the current stack is empty (as can be seen in the screenshot). If I hover over a variable in the code window, the "Variables" window is populated correctly with the stack.
Alternatively, if I switch windows and then bring the "Variables" window back into focus, it is populated correctly with the stack.

Moreover, it is frustrating that after every step-over or step-into (or really any step- operation), this window goes blank again, and I have to revive it using one of the methods described above.

How can I solve this problem? What can I do to ensure that the "Variables" window behaves?

Technical Specs:

- Eclipse `Version: Juno Service Release 1`
- PyDev `2.7.1.2012100913`
- Python `2.7.3`
- OS `Mac OS X 10.7.5`

[image]

Comment: I've seen the same issue on Windows 7 with the same Eclipse, PyDev, and Python versions.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution at all?

Comment: I haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: Please post here if you find something

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows 7 x64, Eclipse 3.8, PyDev 2.7.1. I have to switch 'Show Logical Structure' after each step. OTH, Expression View is working fine!

Comment: I have the same symptoms. Last time I used my debugger (earlier this year I think) it worked fine.
Eclipse 4.2.2
Aptana Pydev 2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee
Ubuntu 12.04 i386 (on an amd64 processor)

Comment: Same issue on Luna 4.4.2, PyDev 4.5.5, Python 3.5 and Windows 10.  The Variables window only seems to be empty when there is a lot of data in the stack.  Toggling show logical structure doesn't show any data for me.  Perhaps there's a max memory setting or something?